# Why is the use of abstractions (such as LINQ) so taboo?

Tags: algorithms, .net, abstraction, linq

I am an independent contractor and, as such, I interview 3-4 times a year for new gigs.  I am in the midst of that cycle now and got turned down for an opportunity even though I felt like the interview went well.  The same thing has happened to me a couple of times this year.

Now, I am not a perfect guy and I don't expect to be a good fit for every organization.  That said, my batting average is lower than usual so I politely asked my last interviewer for some constructive feedback, and he delivered!

The main thing, according to the interviewer, was that I seemed to lean too much towards the use of abstractions (such as LINQ) rather than towards lower-level, organically grown algorithms.

On the surface, this makes sense--in fact, it made the other rejections make sense too because I blabbed about LINQ in those interviews as well and it didn't seem that the interviewers knew much about LINQ (even though they were .NET guys).

**So now I am left with this question:** If we are supposed to be "standing on the shoulders of giants" and using abstractions that are available to us (like LINQ), then why do some folks consider it so taboo?  Doesn't it make sense to pull code "off the shelf" if it accomplishes the same goals without extra cost?

It would seem to me that LINQ, even if it *is* an abstraction, is simply an abstraction of all the *same* algorithms one would write to accomplish exactly the same end.  Only a performance test could tell you if your custom approach was better, but if something like LINQ met the requirements, why bother writing your own classes in the first place?

I don't mean to focus on LINQ here.  I am sure that the JAVA world has something comparable, I just would like to know why some folks get so uncomfortable with the idea of using an abstraction that they themselves did not write.

### UPDATE

As Euphoric pointed out, [there isn't anything comparable to LINQ in the Java world.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1217228/what-is-the-java-equivalent-for-linq)  So, if you are developing on the .NET stack, why not always try and make use of it?  Is it possible that people just don't fully understand what it does?

Comment: I think you don't know what "abstraction" is, because LINQ has nothing to do with it.

Comment: "I am sure that the JAVA world has something comparable" Actually, LINQ is one of the few things, that .NET has and Java doesnt.

Comment: @Euphoric--Does LINQ not *abstract* away the lower level work of tasks such as sorting and filtering for example?  I am quite that sure that there would be some extra code behind `objectCollection.Where(oc=>oc.price > 100)` for example.  Would that not be a use of an abstraction?  Maybe you can tell me what I am missing here. . .

Comment: imo, its kind of an odd thing to reject a .NET candidate over. Were you perhaps too dogmatic about using abstractions in the interview? (for ex, people should always use ORM and never SQL directly).

Comment: @GrandmasterB--Possibly.  I was never asked, "How would you do this task without LINQ".  Only, "In C#, how would you accomplish [foo]".

Comment: In an interview, they want to know if you understand the core of C#, not stuff on top of it.  As the interviewer, I'd assume that you don't know the core stuff, but only the framework.  Better to say, "You could do it this way in C#, and I've also used Linq this way, which simplifies it"

Comment: @Matthew - if LINQ abstracts away the details of implementing a query, there are many other ways of doing that - SQL being a common one. LINQ is troubling as an abstraction because what abstraction does it provide? It's not a database query, because it can query other things, and do other things that aren't queries. In a sense, it's a pure abstraction - like much of mathematics, it invents its own abstraction. That is something it shares with the monads and list comprehensions from functional programming, of course, and is probably enough to trigger some fear-of-the-unknown reactions.

Comment: If your interviewer was so concerned about your fondness for LINQ, why didn't he/she ask more about this, as in give you a coding question on how to do something by hand, rather then using LINQ? This would have shown them that you are happy to do things the "organic" way. I think you were unlucky to have them dismiss you just because you like LINQ so much. Seems a bit stupid quite frankly.

Comment: @Steve314 : But when you are using LINQ you apply exact query on exact data, while expecting exact result. Using LINQ doesn't result in more abstraction. Bashing LINQ for being "abstraction" is like bashing C for "abstracting" jumps behind common loop and code branch constructs.

Comment: @Euphoric - I didn't claim the fear was rational. Interviewers aren't all perfect. Some may even be suspicious of new ideas, particular ideas borrowed from functional languages.

Comment: There is always the chance that they just **don't understand** LINQ and don't see the value in learning it. The functional aspects of writing it are very very different from imperative programming. As a contractor I have as recently as 2009 seen *"senior"* Java developers that don't understand SQL enough to write advanced queries so they spend weeks optimizing code that brings all the data to the Java side and filters it with Java code instead of having the database doing it. **Ignorance** is rampant in the software development industry.

Comment: +1 Jarrod Roberson; that's exactly what I've encountered all during my career.  From the OP It sounds like the interviewer was just clueless and held the fact that the OP knew new technology against him.

Comment: If you understand LINQ but your interviewers don't, you're better than they are. Set your sights higher.

Comment: Next time, bust out the Expression framework, build your own LINQ Expressions that solve the problems using very visible algorithms. Now you've shown that you can write bare metal algorithms but exposed it through a SQL like interface.

Comment: Not clear here if you meant LINQ to objects or LINQ to SQL. Personally I'd expect you to know some LINQ to objects at least.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson: arrogance as well, mind you.

Comment: @haylem in my example they are pretty much the same thing ...

Comment: Unfortunately even though its been around for ages, LINQ (and many many many other things) is still not necessarily mainstream in many .NET development environments, I worked for one organisation recently that explicitly banned usage of LINQ in its coding guidelines because it was "too complicated"!

Comment: Shrug it off. If you're into LINQ, you don't need to try to pretend you're not into it in order to get these clients to like you. They're just not the right kinds of clients for you.

Comment: The Java language does not have anything comparable to LINQ. But the statement that"there isn't anything comparable to LINQ in the Java world" is incorrect. There are constructs / libraries comparable to LINQ that can be used in the Java world / with the JVM, see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3785413/linq-analogues-in-scala. Down voting (-1) until the question has been corrected.

Comment: 80% of the time when I run into resistance regarding LINQ, it is because the other person is thinking about the OR/M tools LINQ-to-SQL and LINQ-to-Entities. When LINQ was first introduced, the OR/M aspect was highly emphasized, so LINQ-to-Objects gets lost amongst newbies. Usually I'll say something about .Where or .Any (to the same person) and I get the response "oh yeah, I love those methods, what are they called?"

Answer (score 74, accepted):

I don't think it's the use of abstractions per se that's objectionable.  There are two other possible explanations.  One is that abstractions are all [leaky](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/LeakyAbstractions.html) at one time or another.  If you give the impression, correct or not, that you don't understand the underlying fundamentals, that might reflect poorly in an interview.

The other possible explanation is the fanboy effect.  If you talk excitedly about LINQ, and repeatedly bring it up in an interview with a company who doesn't use it and has no current plans to do so, that gives the impression that you would be dissatisfied or even disgruntled working with older technologies.  It can also give the impression that your enthusiasm for one product has blinded you to alternatives.

If you truly think you would be happy in a non-LINQ shop, try asking about what they *do* use, and tailor your answers accordingly.  Show them that while you prefer LINQ, you are competent using whatever tools are at hand.

Comment: Karl--Thanks for such a meaningful and helpful answer.  I probably did come across as a fanboy.  I do enjoy using LINQ and can't imagine why one wouldn't use it, but that's sort of your point and something for me to think about.

Comment: @MatthewPatrickCashatt You can't do edit and continue in the debugger inside methods containing linq statements.  It's not enough of a turnoff that I don't use it; but it was the main reason I hesitated in doing so for a while.

Comment: +1, especially for the second paragraph. It totally applies to me, since I would be completely unhappy to work on a C# code without being able to use LINQ.

Comment: There's also the fact that there is frequently a performance hit in addition to the leaky abstraction. You are exchanging ease of use for precision, and that loss of precision frequently includes details that would make things faster. And the further removed you are from the source, the more details you loose and the greater probability that those details are important to performance.

Comment: +1 but it can also work the other way. If someone tells me they did not hire me because I use Yacc to build parsers instead of rolling my own, then it isn't somewhere I want to work anyway.

Comment: @jmoreno--Can you please cite a specific example that proves your point?  I don't mean to come across as rude here (really, I don't), but that is the one thing I have heard thrown out repeatedly and never backed up.  I am actually sure that if you really dug in hard, you could roll your own algorithm that finishes 10ms ahead of a LINQ query, but in most cases, that wouldn't have been worth the effort.  The exceptions would be for organizations like Google or Facebook and I would EXPECT them not to rely on things like LINQ.

Comment: @MatthewPatrickCashatt - Performance drop is simply a kind of an abstraction leak.  It's an extra prolific case because standards generally leave detailed performance levels undefined and it is not always clear what is the "correct" way of coding or compiling a construct performance wise.  Example?  Compare a performance of a prepend-loop and append-loop with a `StringBuilder` in .NET 2.  No difference.  Compare the same code in .NET 4.0.  Drammatic difference that you could not reasonably have expected as it is an implementation detail of the abstraction.

Comment: Drag'n'drop cowboy or one-hammer fanboy are the best guesses at a legit reason behind the rejection, but **honestly, it sounds like they are just idiots and/or are making up excuses** because they just didn't like you or something.

Comment: @MatthewPatrickCashatt: this answer (and my comment on it) are not specific to LINQ, but general statements. But for LINQ, [here's](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/speedinguplinqtosql.aspx)an excerpt from C#4.0/5.0 in a Nutshell, talking about performance problems with LINQ. Back to generalities: in lots of cases the performance hit will be well worth it, 5% +/- being irrelevant.  But sometimes it will be larger and sometimes even .1% is unacceptable. If you don't think there can ever be an issue, or that performance is only for companies like google....

Comment: Thanks for the comment jmoreno.  I hear what you are saying--and of course I think that performance is an issue--but I have to point you back to the OP: Why are abstractions so taboo?  It's easy to generalize, but you have even pointed out in general that in 'lots' (I would say 'most') of cases the 5% performance hit (if indeed it is that much) is well worth it, especially in a cost/benefit analysis situation.  So again, if that is the case, why the taboo?

Comment: @MatthewPatrickCashatt At least in the places I have worked, abstractions are NOT taboo per se and we have made use of LINQ at times.  With that said, the last time I did performance testing (an earlier version, may have improved by now) the perfromance difference between LINQ and hand tuned T-SQL was huge, far too much to justify the advantages of that particular abstraction.

Answer (score 29):

Some .NET programmers, particularly those coming from either a classic VB/ASP or a C++ background, don't like new stuff like LINQ, MVC and Entity Framework.

Based on what I've observed, the ex-VB'ers in this group are likely to still be using a data access layers and other code originally written 10+ years ago. They'll also use old buzzwords like "n-tier" and the like and not really understand anything at all about anything beyond .NET Framework 2.0 nor are they wanting to learn anything about it.

The C++'ers tend to be academically oriented programmers who love coding cool algorithms, even if it means re-inventing the wheel. They hate depending on anything they didn't hand code themselves. A few of these people also delight in making interviewees feel inferior, especially those with a less traditional background.

You're likely to run into organizations like this when you're interviewing. But, you'll also run into some who are using newer methods. Don't let a few bad interviews throw you off.

Comment: Thanks jfrankcarr.  I suspected that this may be the case--there were questions about opening and closing `datareaders`!

Comment: +1 for calling MVC "new stuff."  Made me laugh out loud.  [It's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) been around since the 70's.  You may have meant MVVM which is essentially MVP (an MVC variant) that uses bindings.

Comment: More like ASP.NET MVC, as opposed to ASP.NET WebForms. MVP is Microsoft's buzzword for WPF/Silverlight.

Comment: @GlenH7 I think it was pretty clear from context that he meant the product "ASP.NET MVC", not the basic concept of Model-View-Controller.

Comment: @GlenH7 - I was speaking entirely within the context of the .NET and Visual Studio product line and Microsoft's product buzzwords.

Comment: I would imagine that people who "hate depending on anything they didn't hand code themselves" would use C or Fortran instead, or even assembly. And yes, people still do write assembly http://grc.com

Comment: Good god, are there really shops that think of Linq as "new"? It's been around for over 4 years already. I can understand not having caught up to task awaiters, or to the use of `dynamic`/`ExpandoObject`/etc., or to not caring about Azure and all of the other cloud stuff... I can even understand continuing to use the old-school WebForms view engine in MVC or Web Forms itself, or writing WPF/WinRT code without MVVM... but *Linq?* If you haven't figured that out yet, it's time to quit your job as a .NET developer.

Comment: Your opinion of "C++'ers" is really wrong. That's more C-with-classes guys. True C++ programmers use <algorithm>, boost and/or Poco and never reinvent anything. Actually that's true of any good programmer.

Comment: @Aaronaught - It surprised me. Over the past 3-4 years until I found a perm position, I did a lot of contracting and interviewing. Shops that were in the VB.NET camp I mentioned were often scared to death of LINQ.

Comment: @J.N. - I'm just describing what I've seen in several interviews for C# and .NET development positions. It is likely that a "real C++" programmer wouldn't be coding in C# anyway. Maybe a better way to describe them would have been academically oriented programmers.

Comment: As a long time VB guy, I held out against LINQ & EF for the longest time.  The fanboy hype was such a turnoff.  I was one of the few that knew how to use strongly typed datasets properly and loved them.  But when I finally broke down and started using LINQ + EF, I was amazed.  Incredibly frustrated by the learning curve, but amazed.  IMHO the main shortcoming of LINQ is the lack of clear organized documentation on aggregate functionality that is so easy in SQL, but very very tricky in vb.net LINQ.

Answer (score 16):

Microsoft has a long history of coming out with hot new technologies and then forgetting about them 5, 10, or 20 years down the road. [LINQ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query) might look like another one to some people. They'll note that Microsoft **cannot** deprecate SQL, but LINQ could be following [Silverlight](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Silverlight). So you could be seeing paranoia resulting from hard experience, or just people who've been left behind by modern technology and who resent it.

Comment: I am guessing its the latter part of your statement.  Because I am progressive by nature, and because I firmly believe that you had better keep up with the latest tech if you want to be in this business, I get plenty frustrated with folks out there who are terrified to move away from old, outmoded tech, because it works and everything is status quo--even when they know there are newer, better, and more maintainable ways of doing things.

Comment: Honestly, while I see the basic point, I don't think Linq's going away anytime soon. Linq2SQL, yes, they deprecated it in favor of the much more powerful EF. But Linq itself is the foundation for so much other shiny newness in the last 3 .NET releases that if they deprecated it they'd be undoing half of their new persistence-layer tech like Azure and EF, to say nothing of crippling practically every ORM out there and a LOT of in-memory list-processing besides.

Comment: wait... "terrified to move away from old, outmoded tech, because it works"... WTF. Have we come to the point where working stuff that is tried, tested, understandable and maintainable, and mature is NOT good.

Comment: @gbjbaanb--No. But--as an anecdote--would you want a doctor to diagnose your chest pains with a chest x-ray because that method is 'tried, tested, understandable' or would you want an fMRI that is newer, but comes with higher resolution, better prognosis and more information?  No one is saying to turn away from classic principles here; quite the opposite.  You see, LINQ (as an example) is built upon those principles.  I think, as others have mentioned, it is the learning of the parts that make LINQ and it's proper use that cause the 'WTF' moments such as yours.

Comment: @MatthewPatrickCashatt : depends, if the doctor has not been trained to read the fMRI results, I'd take the x-ray rather than have him guess at a diagnosis.   If I got ill in a backwater, I'd rather have a doctor who could diagnose with nothing more than a stethoscope than be unable to cope without the ultimate in latest tools.

Comment: Thank goodness we don't all work in a backwater!  ;)  Point taken.

Comment: @gbjbaanb more like Lego's vs custom injection molding; the 'new' in programming is most always built atop the 'old'. Most cases the 'old' is not worse, just less convenient to some people. One can argue that MRIs are, however, intrinsically better than X-rays for the reasons mentioned above.

Comment: The concept of LINQ is a fundamental leap in the way people think about data manipulation in a programming language. It can no more be "deprecated" than a for-loop or an if-statement be deprecated. Note: I'm talking about LINQ as a whole, not just the query-style syntax which is entirely optional anyway.

Comment: @MatthewPatrickCashatt I see your point, but a balancing factor is you don't want to follow every trend just because it is newer.  I'll happily follow a new tech that fits into one of two categories. 1. It excites me and I'm willing to spend my free time on it.  2. It proves itself to actually be better and seems like it will last long enough to make it worth the investment.  Trends that do not fit into one of the two categories are a gamble at best.

Comment: People/companies that think that LINQ is related to SQL, are sorely misunderstanding what LINQ is. The name itself doesn't help matters though: "Language Integrated Query" is  a pretty horrible misnomer.

Comment: RalphChapin you've successfully rolled back your edits, there's nothing more we can do here, don't worry about the editor getting credit for their edits, that's what the revision history is for.

Answer (score 15):

> Doesn't it make sense to pull code "off the shelf" if it accomplishes the same goals without extra cost?

**There's always an extra cost.**

The learning curve for off the shelf stuff is always there. The pain of getting updates (and dependencies) is always there. The inability to screw around with the guts is always there.

For LINQ, the first only really applies. Many people consider the 'weird' looking code to be hard to read and harder to debug. The sql-like syntax is pretty much persona-non-grata every professional gig I've worked since it came out. LINQ to SQL (and other data sources) have a number of gotchas and limited optimization options.

These are the general arguments against 3rd party tools and LINQ specifically. All that said, LINQ is a damned useful tool and should be preferred in most situations. Crying Not Invented Here, and abstractions should not be favored smacks strongly of [Cognative Dissonance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cognitive_dissonance).

They don't know/can't learn LINQ, but they're "obviously" good developers, so LINQ must not be worthwhile. It's a common trap.

Comment: Good points.  Agree on the costs that you mention and it's a good clarification.  More broadly, however, developing homegrown classes with which no new employees *can* be familiar because they don't exist outside of the organization presents the same challenges in addition to the cost of primary development.

Comment: @MatthewPatrickCashatt - Oh absolutely. That home-grown code should thus _almost always_ be more effort for the same win, but is not necessarily. Like many other things, the cost/reward should be estimated and the best practice **preferred**, not followed blindly.

Comment: @Telastyn Home-grown code is also nice since you *know* what it does and can fix it at a moments notice. Also, you can optimize for specific circumstances based on your own usage, not an average of everyone's.

Answer (score 13):

Something else you should consider is that your enthusiasm for a cool new technology can simply make people feel uncomfortable and not want you around. You're not "empowering" them, because it's you who knows this technology, not them. Even if they themselves don't realize it, they may be seeking candidates who reinforce what they've already invested so much time into.

You want to present an attitude that says, "Whatever you're doing, I want to help you achieve it", rather than giving a subtext that says, "You might be doing things in a bad way, and having me around will prove it."

Comment: +1 - as well as telling them what you know about, ask them what they are doing and what they specialise in.

Answer (score 12):

My take on this (and TBH I'm guessing because none of us can tell what those interviewers were thinking) is that often you go to an interview to explain why they should hire you *to fit in with their team, their way of working*.

You can be the perfect developer, a rock start code god, but that means absolutely nothing if what you want to do (emphasised by you talking excessively and too enthusiastically about some cool technology gubbins) simply tells them about you, and that you would not fit in with what they want. If they have an old-style data-access system, that cannot be upgrade for whatever reason, they do not need someone who'd forgotten how to maintain it. If they are developing new stuff, and you really really want to put that cool new tech everywhere, then its obvious they will have a big issue with future code maintenance and/or staff training.

As a freelancer, this is much more of a problem that if they were hiring a permie. With a permie, training and development of new ways of working are not bad things, within the scope of existing code and practises - you'll be there for a long while to make things better. With a freelancer, they really don't give a hoot what you want, you're there solely to do their job the way they want it done, and its not your job to do anything else. (disagree - become a permanent employee)

Its probably got nothing to do with LINQ itself, I've rejected a candidate who turned up and explained how much better everything would be written in Haskell. We don't do Haskell. The same applies for any tech that isn't used by the company, usually its not a problem if you mention it as something good. The problem comes when you are too enthusiastic and keen on it.

Comment: I agree with this, but I've noticed a lot more people that use this attitude to dismiss **good** ideas that they just don't understand (e.g. testing, design patterns, ORMs).  So while I agree that being a good fit for the team is a good thing, it's important to realize that you might be better than the rest of the team and should find like-minded individuals where it isn't a bad thing to know good abstractions.

Comment: @WayneM sure, but the OP is a freelancer, so it really doesn't matter if he is a coding god, unless they're prepared to hire him permanently to maintain code the rest of the team doesn't understand (hmm) then he needs to do what they want, not what he wants.

Comment: @WayneM likewise a lot of people would use something similar to what you just said to promote that their ideas over someone else's (being confident that who their talking to simply doesn't get it). In the end both sides are biased, but the OP is about getting hired, not winning the grand DIY/abstraction war. Everyone will have their own opinion, but someone's got to get over it; I'm guessing it won't be the employer in this case. :(

Answer (score 10):

There is one valid concern I've heard from those who don't use Linq, and it's one I take to heart: "Just because you can't see the implementation doesn't mean it isn't expensive".

Take the following snippet:

```
var resultList = inputList.Where(i=>otherInputList.Count(o=>o.Property == i.OtherProperty) > 0);
```

The LINQ-initiated here are cringing. Why? Because just because this code looks nice and elegant doesn't mean it's not horrendously inefficient. Count(), with a predicate, evaluates every element of its parent enumerable, and sums up the times the predicate returned true. So, not only is this N^2 (when inputList and otherInputList are of roughly equal cardinality N), it's the absolute worst-case N^2; EVERY element of otherInputList is traversed for EVERY element of input. Instead, the first step is to use Any() instead of Count, because that's really what you want to know, and it will quit as soon as the answer's known to be "yes". Setting up a HashSet that stores distinct values of `otherInputListObject.OtherProperty` might help you out too; access becomes O(1) instead of O(N), so for an initial linear setup cost you reduce the entire operation to linear *worst-case* complexity instead of quadratic *best-case* complexity.

Thus we see that these nice elegant methods have serious costs behind them, and if you don't know what those costs are, you can very easily code an *O*(my G-D)-complexity algorithm into your prospective employer's high-performance central file servicer or main landing portal page the next time they might need a tweak. Firing you after you do that doesn't undo what you did, but not hiring you if they think you'd do it would prevent it. So, to avoid this, you have to prove them wrong; discuss what those methods do (meaning you have to know yourself) and their complexity, and how to arrive at the answer in an efficient (NlogN or better) time.

Another concern is the good old "When your only tool is a hammer" argument. Put yourself in the place of the interviewer interviewing this Linq fanboy. The candidate likes Linq, wants to use it, thinks it's the best thing ever. It might even seem that the candidate couldn't code without it, since every programming problem given was solved with Linq. Well what happens when it can't be used? Plenty of .NET 2.0 code still out there, that if it were upgraded would require painful upgrades to servers, user workstations, etc etc, all so you can use your fancy extension methods. As the interviewer, I'd try to get you to show that you could code an efficient sort or use the 2.0 sorting methods if you had to, no matter how much I might agree with you that the Linq libraries and similar extension methods are pretty sweet. An interviewer who doesn't see the point might not even bother trying to get you to show aptitude for anything else; they'll assume you don't have it and move on.

Comment: Why wouldn't you just write your query as `var resultList = inputList.Select(i=>i.Property).Intersect(otherInputList.Select(o=>o.Property));`?  I might have botched that, but my point is that LINQ has better ways of executing the query you mention above (.Join() is another way).  I realize that there are ways to use LINQ that might not be as proficient as other ways, but that doesn't mean you have to rely on those bad implementations.

Comment: @MatthewPatrickCashatt I don't think his point is so much to claim that LINQ is always inefficient - while you can always beat a given LINQ query, some uses give better performance per developer-hour than many non-LINQ approaches. Rather, it can be relatively easy to write a LINQ query that *is* inefficient and not realise it, because the inefficiencies aren't as blatant.

Comment: @JonHanna: Perhaps more to the point, the value of an abstraction is greatly reduced if one must examine what code is "really doing" to determine what uncommon-but-plausible scenarios might cause performance to be many orders of magnitude worse than expected.  If changing from one data structure to another will cause code to run 10,000 times slower, the ability to make such a change without altering any other code may not always be a good thing.

Comment: @supercat: yes and no. Just because knowledge of how something is done in a third-party implementation is critical to understanding performance implications and avoiding inefficiencies, doesn't mean the libraries that encapsulate these tools have less value. It's two sides of the same coin; know the nature of the implementation, and you can use it with a few keystrokes instead of an hour rolling your own. But, you have to know both sides, and the stereotypical Linq fanboy who thinks it's perfect, nothing wrong, use it for everything likely doesn't.

Comment: @KeithS: One thing I think is sorely missing in both Java and .net is a standard means of asking objects or collections various things about themselves.  For example, code which receives an enumerable collection might benefit from knowing whether the number of items and/or the sequence of existing items could ever change, whether the number of items is known to be finite or infinite (or not known either way), and whether the collection inherently knows how many items are in it.  Technologies like LINQ often have to make assumptions about such things that may or may not be correct, and...

Comment: ...it's not always obvious what assumptions are being made.  Countless questions on SO, for example, relate to the fact that LINQ assumes the conditions needed to evaluate a query will persist until such time as items in the sequence are enumerated.  Sometimes this assumption is reasonable, and code generated using such an assumption can in some cases be, literally, infinitely more efficient than code which eagerly enumerates (e.g. when one needs the first few items of an infinite sequence) but I dislike language features which obscure the assumptions that are being made.

Answer (score 10):

This one got a bit long, but it might be helpful to someone so I'll let it be.

I actually encountered something similar, going through a little over 20 interviews last month (a mix of phone and face to face). There definitely was something unexpected going on that I couldn't quite put my finger on.

One of the things I noticed though was that the things that have usually been the center-point of the interview cycles of the past five or six years were decidedly not discussed or given short shrift. Things like the fundamentals of OOP analysis / design, patterns (design and architectural both), some of the more advanced / abstraction oriented .net features (including lambdas or LINQ specifically, generics, serialization / data binding, and similar), and even the usually hot topic of favored methodology (no one seemed to care much about agile vs waterfall or what flavor of agile) and tools or choice of ORM or preferred means of collaboration or source control management. In some cases not mentioned at all, in almost all cases apparently not of concern.

What did receive focus, in multiple interviews and various unrelated firms in unrelated industries, were along these lines:

- A strange fixation on outdated / outmoded conventions and "back to stone ages" limitations. Like developing a primitive web app in VS2003 with a list of absurd restrictions further forbidding the usage of explicit features extent within that era of .net...as if that is a real gauge of a modern developers ability...the ability to remember the paradigm and limitations of 9 years ago further crippled by unrealistic / arbitrary constraints. Another place was very dogged on the subject of custom collections, circa pre-generic collections. Another place dinged a code sample of a class model I scrawled out because I didn't use cascaded constructors (they seemed unaware of the support for property initialization on declaration, which was sufficient to the need). Another place was big on delegates and did not like my response that I used to declare them frequently but I practically never need to declare them anymore thanks to Action<> and Func<>.
- Extreme focus on specific implementation details in a microcosm and / or configuration settings, even in the case of technologies that focus on being platform or protocol agnostic (i.e...the whole point is to NOT be fixated on a specific implementation or particular usage but rather on reuse / re-purposing / extensibility / as needed integration).
- Willingness to spec out / supervise / code review / and otherwise spool off work to and from an off shore team, and non-coding skills related to doing so.
- Usage of specific versions of products / platforms / modules / etc. To a sometimes absurd degree; "So...you've used versions 1, 2, and 4? But not 3, eh? Hmmm...{annotates your resume with "no v3!!!}". Degree of usage did not seem to matter; only that you have or have not used something *at all*, and the specific thing that they are asking for also...no substitutions seemed to count, even of a more widely used and fully featured competing product.
- A far greater amount of focus on "how well will you fit onto our team" over "are you actually any good as a software developer" or "do you have the skills and experience to add value to the company and help us deliver a quality product" or even "are you a dangerous idiot who will come in and wreck shop". In some cases, my resume was just taken as a given, and even the so-called "tech screen" or technical interview was a personality assessment far more than a skills assessment. Even for relatively short term contract positions where you would be there and gone again before two seasons have changed.
- Companies this time around seemed to have much less of a focus on solving specific technical problems, starting new green-field or big 2.0 development projects, or getting a specific product to market to capitalize on an emergent trend or opportunity, or the usual big kickoffs. A repeating theme that I noticed at at least 15 of the places was that a small group of 3-5 developers, mostly survivors of the market crash in 08, were able to grind out a product over the course of the last 3 years or so and found some success or their company as a whole is booming and they are hiring on new folks to keep up with increasing feature demands or to address / overcome the design flaws they built in to these systems, or to take over the aforementioned platforms to free up the core team that built it to do "other projects". The details differed and there were exceptions, but that was the general lay of the land this time around.

But...if there's one thing I know about this business it's that it is cyclical. The next time I'm looking for a new gig, I wont be surprised if the game has changed yet again. You just have to remain mentally flexible, do some active listening, avoid making absolute statements if they are unnecessary but don't be a weasel either, and don't come off as being either one-dimensional (you come of as an idiot or a zealot, neither desirable) or as being *too* good (it can be threatening and cost you a gig).

Just adjust your approach, and try to give a more measured response next time...mention a few different ways you might approach a problem...but even if it is rote knowledge for you act as if you are actually thinking about it and reasoning it out on the spot. It seems more humble and less intimidating or offputting that way.

Of course, Murphy's Law being what it is, the very next interview after you stop being "passionate about my current favorite technology guy" and adopt a more balanced / beard-stroking stance is the gig that you *would* have gotten had you been the crazed zealot guy.  ;)

Answer (score 6):

I think you are drawing a false conclusion, because your set of samples is too limited. Although I have seen a fair share of IT shops with strong aversion to anything "not invented there"<sup>1</sup>, none of them would disqualify candidates based on their preferences in the technology stack: they were rightfully convinced that they could teach the right candidate to use their home-grown libraries.

I seriously doubt that the company banned the use of LINQ outright. More likely, they wanted you to show them your skills at a deeper level.

For example, one way to figure out if you know your hash tables is to ask you to implement a primitive one on a whiteboard. This simple exercise reveals a surprising amount of data about your knowledge to the reviewer: he instantly learns if you know about hash code / equals, and what you know about hash collisions. At the same time, it is hard to imagine someone in their right mind re-implementing a hash table, because Microsoft did so good of a job at it. Same goes for many algorithms, such as sorting and searching: interviewers often would like to know if your background is enough to understand low-level interactions, rather than checking that you have a working knowledge of .NET libraries.

It is a near certainty that they would *insist* on you using library implementations rather than your own once you are hired to work for their company. But during the interview they would push you toward the low level code to gain better understanding of your true abilities.

---

<sup>1</sup> one shop went as far as building its own rather primitive build tool!

Comment: All of your points are well made, but I should give you some color around the last interview: the interviewer insisted that LINQ was being "deprecated".  I asked, "don't you mean that MS will no longer be investing in Linq-to-SQL but that Linq-to-Entities will be around" and his reply was that he meant what he said: LINQ is being "deprecated" so, no I don't think that he knew too much about LINQ or would insist upon it's use.

Comment: @MatthewPatrickCashatt If someone confused LINQ for LINQ2SQL in terms of the technology being deprecated, I'd made up some silly excuse to leave the interview early, and never called that company back. If that was indeed the case, you should be happy about them not hiring you :)

Comment: 100% certain that was the case.  In fact, I couldn't resist sending  him some links to set him on the right path on the subject, not as a jab since I didn't get the gig, but because I actually felt embarrassed for him and was hoping that I could help him to not make the same mistake twice ;).

Comment: Then this appears to have less to do with the technology stack and more to do with the fact that you corrected him.  People don't like to be corrected.  It's just human nature.  When people make decisions such as hiring people, 99% will go with their intuition.  They go by whether or not you caused them to feel positive or negative emotions.  Correcting him may have caused him to feel negative emotions.  And he then associates that negativity with the situation.

Comment: @coder there is a name for it: cognitive dissonance.

Comment: I don't know how hashtables work internally. Deep technical tests like that throw out people with practically minded training that are good candidates nonetheless. Requiring people to have low level knowledge they will never use seems unnecessary to me. Design principles have become much more important!

Comment: @Tjaart "I don't know how hashtables work internally" quite frankly, this is not a thing I would brag about. This is much farther from the kind of "low level knowledge they will never use" that you think it is. For example, without this knowledge you stand no chance of knowing why `int GetHashCode() {return firstName.GetHashCode()%10 - lastName.GetHashCode()%10;}` is a great way to ensure a disastrously bad performance. The "design principles" learned before the ABCs of data structures are sitting on a shaky foundation.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I am most certainly not bragging. I am being honest about my skills. Who in their right mind would brag about their ignorance!? I take this as being an unnecessary personal insult to my character. If I need to know how something works I will learn, but your "shaky foundation" is merely your opinion. I've never needed to write the code you quoted as an example. If I do I will be sure to study hashtables in detail.

Comment: @Tjaart "shaky foundation" is more of an observation: modern computer systems have too many layers to learn, so the knowledge will necessarily "bottom out" in one of them. In general, the lower - the better; knowing the details of electronic bus signaling is probably too low (although it wouldn't hurt). However, details of hash tables, one of three basic data structures in CS (the other two being arrays and binary trees), is too high. The "just in time learning" model does not work there, because unless you know what to write, you wouldn't know that you need to write anything at all.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I have never spotted any of those algorithms in code I had to maintain, or even code I had an interest in. It used to be much more important, and still is for people working in the lower end. You yourself mention that there is a near zero chance that you would want anyone re-writing those algorithms, yet you see it as a requirement for developers. I learned all 3 those basic structures during school/study time, although hashtable internals never stuck, because I have never had a use for it. If you hire with those criteria I am convinced you could miss out on good developers.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight - There is a wide swath of dev jobs out there that do not require the kind of detail you are talking about. "Put up a page on the intranet where the 7 sales guys can enter their daily totals. And get it done by tomorrow." That type of job requires broad knowledge of how to use appropriate frameworks to get simple work done quickly, but not necessarily deep knowledge of the language. Its where I've spent my 8 year career so far.

Answer (score 4):

I think you're making some mad generalisations there of the "I saw a black cow in Scotland, so all Scottish cows are black" type.

If I interviewed you I'd be disappointed if you couldn't answer my linq questions.

Linq is a tricky one though, a lot of people see it as voodoo which is unfair as it's actually very simple and all the more clever for it.

Answer (score 3):

To play devil's advocate, the reason is many developers just don't care about new things and think everything has to be solved with homegrown (usually inferior) tools.  There's nothing wrong with using abstractions.  Hell, there usually is no good reason **not** to use those abstractions.

It sounds like you just interviewed with a poor developer that doesn't keep up to date with things and takes the hammer and nail approach to everything.  These are the types of developers that don't know anything about helpful open source tools like NUnit, or NHibernate, or the various IoC containers; the ones who try to solve every problem with a massive stored proc in the database; the ones that know absolutely nothing about MVC despite it being out for several years now.

Comment: You may throw LINQ into a buzzword pool containing Nhibernate etc... I would not do that. Actually I think buzzwords exemplify our inability to explain abstractions into proper expressions.

Comment: You are talking about 'keeping up to date' well I think the inverse wOuld be very much more appropriate. Many useful concepts have been discovered and used in the past, for example DSL's . It is up to us to improve our communication and grasp of concepts such as that we don't need to invent new buzz words for old concepts.